# select case statement add information

Tags: sql, sum, db2

I have 2 tables cardinfo and paytb. In my statement I joined them by the CONT_ID.

```
 select (case when age_years >= 18 and age_years < 30 then '18-29'
            when age_years < 50 then '30-49'
            when age_years < 70 then '50-69'
             when age_years < 100 then '70-100'
            end) as age_range,
             count(DISTINCT c.CONT_ID) as num,
     CASE WHEN GENDER = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END / COUNT(DISTINCT c.CONT_ID),
     SUM(ACAUREQ_AUREQ_TX_DT_TTLAMT) / COUNT(*) 'TOTAL-Amount Avg' 
         from cardinfo c
         left join paytb t
          on c.CONT_ID = t.CONT_ID
      group by (case when age_years >= 18 and age_years < 30 then '18-29'
         when age_years < 50 then '30-49'
         when age_years < 70 then '50-69'
         when age_years < 100 then '70-100'
         end)
         order by min(age_years);
```

Now this shows the first 2 columns  of:

```
 AGE_RANGE          NUM      GENDER      
---------+---------+----------------
18-29              828        50%        
30-49             2510        ??         
50-69             2014        ??         
70-100             649
```

I want to add the GENDER parameter (0 or 1) from the Table. However this is not working:

```
CASE WHEN GENDER = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END / COUNT(DISTINCT c.CONT_ID)
```

sqlcode= -122

And I tryed to find the average of the transactions:

```
SUM(ACAUREQ_AUREQ_TX_DT_TTLAMT) / COUNT(*) 'TOTAL-Amount Avg'
```

Unfortunatly this will give me a DECFLOAT error.
The sum looks like this:

```
  SUM(ACAUREQ_AUREQ_TX_DT_TTLAMT)
    -----+---------+---------+---------+
    +1.232071426000000000000000E+0007   
    +3.062581021000000000000000E+0007   
    +2.399951792000000000000000E+0007   
    +8.228919170000000000000000E+0006
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd wrap the original query up in a derived table, to save some typing:

```
select age_range,
       count(DISTINCT CONT_ID) as num,
       CASE WHEN GENDER = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END / COUNT(DISTINCT c.CONT_ID),
       SUM(ACAUREQ_AUREQ_TX_DT_TTLAMT) / COUNT(*) 'TOTAL-Amount Avg' 
from
(
    select (case when age_years >= 18 and age_years < 30 then '18-29'
                 when age_years < 50 then '30-49'
                 when age_years < 70 then '50-69'
                 when age_years < 100 then '70-100'
            end) as age_range,
            c.CONT_ID,
            GENDER,
            ACAUREQ_AUREQ_TX_DT_TTLAMT
    from CARDUSR.CLIENT_INFO c
    left join cardusr.sppaytb t
        on c.CONT_ID = t.CONT_ID
)
group by age_range, GENDER
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either include `gender` in the `group by` or make it the argument to an aggregation function:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(DISTINCT c.CONT_ID)
```

However, you probably don't need the `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  If it is not necessary, you can simplify this to:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN GENDER = '1' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: That worked out, I will have to add alot more columns to this. Like the most frequent ACAUREQ_AUREQ_ENV_M_CMONNM - ( Common Merchant Name ). How would that look like?

Comment: @bastel . . . I'm not sure what you want but `SUM(CASE . . .)` and `AVG(CASE . . .)` are a common constructs.